# How can i read a specific char inside a file?

Tags: c

This would be enough to read the first character `'a'` inside `fp`

```
file.txt

abcdef
```

```c
// readchar.c

FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int c = fgetc(fp);
```

but how can i read (e.g.) the 3rd character?

Comment: You just read all the characters before it first. Or if you really want to you can `fseek` straight to it if you know exactly where in the file it is.

Comment: Honestly I'd just wait for `readfile(2)` to make it to mainline kernel

Comment: Use fgets to read a whole line and then look at the third item in the array?

Comment: The baseline, mainstream way would be `fseek`.  Or you could try `mmap`.

Comment: `char c = fgetc(fp);` should be `int c = fgetc(fp);`.  `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  If you cram the result into a `char` you won't be able to reliably detect `EOF` because `EOF` is deliberately chosen to be an `int` value with a bit pattern that a `char` can not have.

Comment: For the third char, I would just copy the line, paste it twice and move on....

Comment: See [man 3 fseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) for the collection of functions that allow you to jump to a specific position within an open file stream. Keep the [Linux man pages online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) link for handy future reference. (or if you are using Linux, just open a terminal and type `man fseek`, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

A text file is a kind of *sequential file*. To read a specific item, you must read everything preceding it in the file.

Operating systems let you read a file anywhere by moving a so called *file pointer*. The position in the file where read take place can be changed by *seeking* into the file. There are several ways to handle file I/O. The one you found invoke `fopen` to open the file and get a file pointer, `fgetc`to read the next character where the *file pointer* points and advance it by one character. You have `fgets`to read a complete line. `fseek` to more the file pointer somewhere else. `fclose`to close the file. And other similar function.

Back to the text file. Assuming we have a file containing: two lines containing:

```
Hello world,
Programming rocks!
```

If you want to read the 5th character of the first line, it is easy: just position the file pointer with `fseek` to the 5th position in the file (the first character is at position zero). Then read it with `fgetc`.

Now if you need to read the 5th character of the second line, whatever the first line is, you cannot use `fseek` because you don't know the length of the first line without reading the line first.

To read the Nth character on the Mth line, you must read M lines, throwing away data except the last one (You simply read all line in a for/loop into the same buffer). And then access the Nth character in the buffer where you just read the last line. Make that buffer an *array of char* and you have direct access to the Nth character.